# Copy Bootstrap styles to my CSS class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to apply Bootstrap's list-group styles to my selector

```
my_class > some_selector > ul
my_class > some_selector > ul > li
```

I want to use the same styles as list-group styles of Bootstrap. Is it possible to copy the styles of list-group and list-group-item to my selectors?

I am using bootstrap-sass and Bootstrap 3.x.

Comment: Maybe you add bootstrap classes to your html elements?

Comment: I don't have control over the markup. It's generated by a markdown generator. But I can write my own styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SASS' `extend` for this. A nice example is provided [in their documentation](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7).

Basically, in your rule, you can add `@extend .bootstrap-class` to add those properties to your selector.

More specifically for [list-group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group), you probably want something along the lines of:

```
.my_class > some_selector > ul {
  @extend .list-group;
  /* custom styles */

  > li {
    @extend .list-group-item;
    /* custom styles */
  }
}
```